# Django annotate to foreign key model

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to manage some translations in a simple way using a JSON field.

The translation needs to sortable and filterable.

Given the following models:

```py
class Alarm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    value = models.BooleanField()
    name_translations = JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default={})
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)

class HistoryAlarm(models.Model):
    alarm = models.ForeignKey(Alarm, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.BooleanField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
```

I can do the following:

```py
alarm_list = Alarm.objects.all().annotate(
    translated_name=KeyTextTransform('en-US', 'name_translations')
)

alarm_list[0].translated_name

> "Translation alarm 0"

alarm_list = Alarm.objects.all().annotate(
    translated_name=KeyTextTransform('it-IT', 'name_translations')
)

alarm_list[0].translated_name

> "Traduzione allarme 0"
```

How would I write the queryset so that I could do this?

```py
history_alarm_list = ???

history_alarm_list[0].alarm.translated_name

> "Traduzione allarme 0"
```

What I got so far is this, but it binds `translated_name` to history_alarm, not alarm:

```py
history_alarm_list = HistoryAlarm.objects.annotate(
    translated_name=KeyTextTransform('it-IT', 'alarm__name_translations')
)

history_alarm_list[0].translated_name

> "Traduzione allarme 0"
```

There reason why I need to do it this way is because:

- I have 2 serializers: AlarmSerializer and HistoryAlarmSerializer
- I would like to use my AlarmSerializer to serializer the alarm attribute of my HistoryAlarm model.
- Finally, if I define `translated_name` in my AlarmSerializer it has to be there also when I serialize my HistoryAlarms records.

```py
class AlarmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    translated_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_translated_name(self, obj):
        return obj.translated_name

    class Meta:
        model = Alarm
        fields = '__all__'

class HistoryAlarmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    alarm = AlarmSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = HistoryAlarm
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Can you explain your intention in *English*?

Comment: @JPG, surely, I just updated the question.

Comment: can you add those serializer class?

Comment: @JPG Added at the botton of the question.

Comment: corrected a method was missing

Comment: Which model are you trying to serialiZe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193124/discussion-between-pnknrg-and-jpg).